# How can i extract unicode concat string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode

[image]

I would like to extract last value after the "dot".

When I copy the cell value --> it shows like 00.250.980.80.19

Is this Unicode stuff?

How can I decode the string and extract the last one?

Thanks

Comment: find out what is the ASCII code of that character and then you can split the string to extract the values

Comment: Your question is not clear. what happens when you do `SELECT LEN(TOT_ACCR_AMT) FROM TableName` what have you tried so far can you show your attempt / SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ASCII](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ascii-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function to find the code of your `dot`. For example:

```
SELECT ASCII(N'·'); -- 183
```

Then, you can use [CHAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/char-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function to transform an int ASCII code to a character value and [SUBSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(32) = N'·05·201·41·321·32·501';

SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@string), 0, CHARINDEX(CHAR(183), REVERSE(@string)))); -- 501
```

of course if you can simply use the `char` itself:

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(32) = N'·05·201·41·321·32·501';

SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@string), 0, CHARINDEX('·', REVERSE(@string)))); -- 501
```